# fetchSize property on a DB2 database (JDBC)

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I am looking into improving performance of a select query on a DB2 database with millions of rows. I do not have access yet unfortunately and cannot test it.
So I try to read through the documentation and there is a statement that confuses me. The statement is in bold and italic saying that `the fetchSize property does not affect Statement objects that exist when fetchSize is set.`

As far as I know I have to create a `Statement` object in order to set the `fetchSize` property and that is how I see and do it in the program code.
Also, that statement somehow contradicts its previous sentence saying that one can use `Statement.setFetchSize method` to set the fetch size.

Can anyone clarify or could share his/her experience with JDBC/fetchSize/DB2 ?

In the documentation of IBM (see [link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=pdsdjs-common-data-server-driver-jdbc-sqlj-properties-all-database-products)):

> **fetchSize**
>
> Specifies the default fetch size for ResultSet objects that
> are generated from Statement objects. The data type of this property
> is int.
>
> The fetchSize default can be overridden by the
> Statement.setFetchSize method.
> ***The fetchSize property does not affect Statement objects that exist when fetchSize is set.***
>
> Possible values of fetchSize are:
>
> **0 or positive-integer**
>
> The default fetchSize value for newly created
> Statement objects. If the fetchSize property value is invalid, the IBM
> Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ sets the default fetchSize value
> to 0.
>
> **DB2BaseDataSource.FETCHSIZE_NOT_SET (-1)**
>
> Indicates that the default fetchSize value for Statement objects is 0.
> This value is the property default. The fetchSize property differs from the
> queryDataSize property. fetchSize affects the number of rows that are
> returned, and queryDataSize affects the number of bytes that are
> returned.

Comment: I think it means it has no effect if called after an `execute***` has been called on a `Statement`, but it's very poorly written. This means it can't be used to tune the fetch size on-the-fly, but you need to decide it up front. Fetch size is one of the most annoyingly complicated things to exist in JDBC. Also the documentation is garbage, it has no explanation what a fetch size of 0 implies.

Comment: One may try in addition: `queryDataSize`: 32KB (default), 256KB (max until 11.5.7), 10MB (max since 11.5.7), `queryPrefetch=true` (since 11.5.6).

Comment: When you get access to Db2, (or even indirect access via a helpful DBA if available) then the place to start optimising might not be with the fetch size, but with the access plan for the query.

Answer (score 1):

What it means is that the `fetchSize` value set at the connection level is used by default for all future `Statement` objects, unless it's overridden by `Statement.fetchSize()`. Changing `fetchSize` at the connection level will have no effect on `Statement`s created previously.